# How could you make this really reaaally complicated raw SQL query with django's ORM?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Good day, everyone. Hope you're doing well. I'm a Django newbie, trying to learn the basics of RESTful development while helping in a small app project. Currently, there's a really difficult query that I must do to create a calculated field that updates my student's status accordingly to the time interval the classes are in. First, let me explain the models:

```
class StudentReport(models.Model): 

    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    headroom_teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    upload = models.ForeignKey(Upload, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='reports', blank=True, null=True,)
    exams_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
    #Other fields that don't matter

class ExamCycle(models.Model):

    student = models.ForeignKey(student, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)     
    headroom_teacher = models.ForeignKey(Teacher, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    #Other fields that don't matter

class RecommendedClasses(models.Model):
    report = models.ForeignKey(Report, on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    range_start = models.DateField(null=True)
    range_end = models.DateField(null=True)
    
    # Other fields that don't matter

class StudentStatus(models.TextChoices):
    enrolled = 'enrolled' #started class
    anxious_for_exams = 'anxious_for_exams'
    sticked_with_it = 'sticked_with_it' #already passed one cycle
```

So this app will help the management of a Cram school. We first do an initial report of the student and its best/worst subjects in `StudentReport`. Then a `RecommendedClasses` object is created that tells him which clases he should enroll in. Finally, we have a cycle of exams (let's say 4 times a year). After he completes each exam, another report is created and he can be recommended a new class or to move on the next level of its previous class.

I'll use the choices in `StudentStatus` to calculate an annotated field that I will call `status` on my `RecommendedClasses` report model. I'm having issues with the `sticked_with_it` status because it's a query that it's done after one cycle is completed and two reports have been made (Two because this query **must** be done in StudentStatus, after 2nd Report is created).  A `'sticked_with_it'` student has a report created after `exams_date` where `RecommendedClasses` was created and the future `exams_date` time value falls within the 30 days before `range_start` and 60 days after the `range_end` values of the recommendation (Don't question this, it's just the way  the higherups want the status)

I have already come up with two ways to do it, but one is with a RAW SQL query and the other is waaay to complicated and slow. Here it is:

```
SELECT rec.id AS rec_id FROM
                school_recommendedclasses rec LEFT JOIN
                school_report original_report
                ON rec.report_id = original_report.id
                AND rec.teacher_id = original_report.teacher_id
                JOIN reports_report2 future_report
                    ON future_report.exams_date > original_report.exams_date
                    AND future_report.student_id = original_report.student_id
                    AND future_report.`exams_date` > (rec.`range_start` - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
                    AND future_report.`exams_date` <
                        (rec.`range_end` + INTERVAL 60 DAY)
                    AND original_report.student_id = future_report.student_id
```

How can I transfer this to a proper DJANGO ORM that is not so painfully unoptimized? I'll show you the other way in the comments.

Comment: There's no benefit in including the same comparison twice, and the subsequent joins suggest that the opening join should also be an inner rather than an outer join

Comment: Other than that, this query seems clear and concise

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the 3 tables.  And `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`  And roughly how big each table is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW, I find this easier to read, but there's very little wrong with your query.

Transforming this to your ORM should be straightforward, and any further optimisations are down to indexes...

```
SELECT r.id rec_id 
  FROM reports_recommendation r  
  JOIN reports_report2 o
    ON o.id = r.report_id 
   AND o.provider_id = r.provider_id 
  JOIN reports_report2 f
    ON f.initial_exam_date > o.initial_exam_date
   AND f.patient_id = o.patient_id
   AND f.initial_exam_date > r.range_start - INTERVAL 30 DAY
   AND f.initial_exam_date < r.range_end + INTERVAL 60 DAY
   AND f.provider_id = o.provider_id
```

Comment: Thank you, Strawberry. But when it comes to the ORM, I'm still very noob. I've been racking my head for days trying to find the correct expression for it. As I said on the post, I came up with something but it was really slow and a long ass ORM expression. Could you please show me how you'd do this with the ORM?

Comment: I don't know django (actually, I don't know other frameworks either). I imagined that you'd be able to construct a query similar to the way you do in Laravel, but that seems not to be the case, so I think you would just go with the raw query.